# Getting error when changing "applicationId" in gradle (No matching client found for package name "my_new_app_id")

Tags: android, gradle

I am trying to change applicationId in my app gradle and getting below error in Android Studio 3.0.1.

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
>   No matching client found for package name 'my_new_app_id'

Comment: Did you configure your `google-services.json` file properly ?

Comment: Configure your project in Firebase console, make sure to enter the correct package name and then download and keep the json file in your app module.

Comment: I have not change the package name of my application, i only change the applicationid thats why package name in firebase console and json file not changed, and firebase configured before change in application id.... Do i need to change the applicationid in firebase console???

Answer (score 3):

Internally, Firebase uses `application id` in order to configure our app. So If you have changed the application id in the meanwhile, make sure to remove the project from console, add it once again, configure the keys and then add the `google-services.json` file in the root of app module directory in order to get your project working.